# No enclosing instance of type foo is accessible. Why?

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

I'am learning about Interfaces and created the following program to test the interface that I created:

```
public class InterfaceTestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterfaceTestClass x = new InterfaceTestClass();
        Object[] foodItems = { new Apple(), x.new Chicken(), x.new Tiger() };
        for (int i = 0; i < foodItems.length; i++) {
            if (foodItems[i] instanceof Edible) {
                ((Edible) (foodItems[i])).howToEat();
            }
            if (foodItems[i] instanceof Tiger) {
                ((Tiger) (foodItems[i])).howToEat();
            }

        }
    }

    public interface Edible {
        void howToEat();
    }

    public class Apple implements Edible {
        @Override
        public void howToEat() {
            System.out.println("Eat apple as salad");
        }
    }

    public class Chicken implements Edible {

        @Override
        public void howToEat() {
            System.out.println("Eat Chicken with rice");
        }

    }

    public class Tiger {
        public void howToEat() {
            System.out.println("This is not edible");
        }
    }
}
```

If I do not put the 'x' before 'new Apple()' or Chiken or Tiger I get an error message same as the one in this question's title. Why is it so?

```
Object[] foodItems = { x.new Apple(), x.new Chicken(), x.new Tiger() };
```

Comment: What you want to achieve by your code?

Comment: @MohhitTomar Please post complete code. We can only guess how `Apple`, `Chicken`, `Tiger` are declared.

Comment: Following is the complete code, I did not include it before to keep the question short. Also I'm new to StackOverflow and dont fully understand how to put my comments and replies

Comment: There is nothing specific that I'm trying to achieve, I'am still learning to code. And very new to coding and StackOverflow. You can guess that by looking at my code.. ;-) Thanks

Comment: So basically the problem is that all of those classes are inner classes - they're declared within `InterfaceTestClass`. Is there any reason you've done that? Inner classes are generally more complex to work with than top-level classes - you should only use an inner class if you know you really need to.

Comment: I think I read that an inner class is the one that is declared inside the body of another class. Though I declared all interface and class in the same file I don't think these are inner classes, or are they? Sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: Look at where `Tiger` (for example) is declared. It's declared within `InterfaceTestClass`. That makes it a nested class. It's not declared with the `static` modifier, therefore it's an inner class. I'd suggest using a separate source file for each class, and avoiding inner classes unless you really need them.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Oh yes I see I made these classes as nested classes. Thanks for your time

Comment: @MohitTomar check my answer below. I have tried to explain what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes `Chicken` and `Apple` are Inner Classes and the way to access any Inner Class's function is `OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass()`.

You have created the object of Outer Class here: `InterfaceTestClass x = new InterfaceTestClass();` and thus when you put `x.new Chicken()` you are facilitating the use of Inner Class function.

Look up Inner Classes to understand the concept better. I hope this helped.

Comment: Time to revise my notes.. Thanks :-)